# Substring that matches a regex in python

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

Im trying to get a substring that matches a regex in python, its a price obtained from scraping a supermarket website. My code looks like this:

```
import scrapy
import re

class namePriceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'namePrice'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.cotodigital3.com.ar/sitios/cdigi/browse/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        all_category_products = response.xpath('//*[@id="products"]')
        for product in all_category_products:
            name = product.xpath('//div[@class="descrip_full"]/text()').extract()
            price = product.xpath('//span[@class ="atg_store_newPrice"]/text()').extract()
            yield {'name': name,
                   'price': re.search(r'$\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?:[.,]\d{2})', price).group(1)}
```

When i run the spider, i get this error line 16, in parse
'price': re.search(r'$\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?:[.,]\d{2})', price).group(1)} and TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.

Comment: One thing I see is that the dollar sign, `$`, needs to be escaped, `\$` as it is a metacharacter (for end of line). Also, you have no capturing parentheses so `group(1)` has nothing to refer to. I think you could use `group(0)` here.

Comment: `.extract()` returns a list, but search expects a string. Use `extract_first` or loop over the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved it, it had multiple errors but the biggest one was that price shouldn't have .extract(), it should be like this

```
price = product.xpath('//span[@class="atg_store_productPrice" and not(@style)]/span[@class '
                                  '="atg_store_newPrice"]/text() | //span[@class="price_discount"]/text()').re(
                r'\$\d{'
                r'1,'
                r'5}(?:['
                r'.,'
                r']\d{'
                r'3})*('
                r'?:[., '
                r']\d{2})*')
```